# Getting features using objectID in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, objectid, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

In ArcGIS Server 10.2, there is a method named `lookupFeatureWithObjectId` in the class `AGSFeatureLayer.h`.

However, there is no such method in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS version 100.x.

How can i manipulate such functionality using new version of ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS?

Comment: My understanding is that the latest version of ArcGIS Server is 10.6.  Where have you found ArcGIS Server version 100.x?

Comment: @PolyGeo - He's talking about the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS 100.2

Comment: @GISGe I'll assume that you are right and have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks.. yes it's ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS.

Comment: @GISGe, thanks .Yes, it's ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

With knowing only very little of your problem, i'll try to answer your question as best as I can.

Might I suggest you use the method:
[selectFeaturesWithQuery:mode:completion:()](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_feature_layer.html#ae655af6edce13c49c841f0556dc6d561)

In which you'll need to provide a `AGSQueryParameters` parameter where you supply a [whereClause](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_query_parameters.html#a6015ca83530bf76d64a50f63b91bdb9c) in which you set `"OBJECTID = \(id)"`

Please note that `OBJECTID` must be identical to the Object ID you have in your feature layer service schema. Also, you might need to put the value of `id` within brackets and quotes to better match a SQL-like where clause in case your Object ID is of type UUID. So that would look like: `"OBJECTID = \'{\(id)}\'"`

If you provide more information, i'd be happy to look into this issue further.

Good luck!